# Converting text to javascript and executing it

Tags: javascript, jquery, codemirror

I have got formatted text(which is a piece of code) in my textarea which is beautified using the codemirror. 
Now when I press the button under the textaera,I need to pass a response as a variable to the above code and execute it as javascript and obtain the result.
basically I just want something similar to jsfiddle.

How can I do this using javascript/jquery?. Is there any plugins that I could use for the same?

Comment: the notorious http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for eval function in JavaScript. I do not understand what exactly you need to achieve, but this might help:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp

However, as I understand you should try to avoid eval in the code, but if this is the only way, let it be.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the code in an iframe on a different domain with [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) function, this causes the browser to not allow the code in the iframe access to the parent page due to the [Same Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Well known tools created to run third-party code is [Google Caja](https://developers.google.com/caja/) and [ADsafe](http://www.adsafe.org/).